# Check existing total at the end of a range of values

Tags: excel, vba

I want to check the value in Total at the end of a range of values.

For a selected static range (here `A1:A4`), I need the actual total of range (CalcTotal) after the existing Total cell followed by Diff.

Data:

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ClassA | 25 |
| 2 | ClassB | 14 |
| 3 | ClassC | 78 |
| 4 | ClassD | 34 |
| 5 | Total | 180 |
| 6 | CalcTotal | 151 |
| 7 | Diff | 29 |

Answer (score 2):

### Check Totals

[image]

```vb
Sub CheckTotals()
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    If Selection Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Not TypeOf Selection Is Range Then Exit Sub

    Dim cSum As Double

    With Selection
        cSum = Application.Sum(.Columns(2).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1))
        With .Resize(2).Offset(.Rows.Count)
            .Cells(1).Value = "CalcTotal"
            .Cells(3).Value = "Diff"
            .Cells(2).Value = cSum
            .Cells(4).Value = .Cells(1).Offset(-1, 1).Value - cSum
        End With
    End With
    
ProcExit:
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    MsgBox "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & vbLf _
        & Err.Description & vbLf & vbLf _
        & "For this to work, select 2 columns (the right one with numbers) " _
        & "and include the total row!", vbCritical
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Mr VBasic2008, it is working as desired.